# How can I recover a missing body part without using wish?

Tags: dnd-5e, injury, regeneration

I recently had my nose bitten off by a berserker and smell is surprisingly hard to live without.

I have had some past trouble with wishes (from a ring of three wishes) so I'm reluctant to make another wish. Also I don't think this is worth wasting my last wish over anyway.  My DM is evil so I'll probably end up with a Mephit's nose or something if I wish for it back.

Can anyone tell me another way of regaining body parts?

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/171318/can-a-ring-of-regeneration-regrow-body-parts-lost-before-you-attuned-it/171319

Answer (score 36):

## Use Regenerate, a 7th level spell.

It is on the Bard, Cleric, and Druid spell lists.
You can also use a Wish to duplicate this spell without needing to worry about it going badly (evil genie does not apply when duplicating spells up to 8th level).

One of the effects of the spell is:

> **The target’s severed body members (fingers, legs, tails, and so on), if any, are restored after 2 minutes.** If you have the severed part and hold it to the stump, the spell instantaneously causes the limb to knit to the stump.

*Emphasis added*

There is also a magical item that could help.  The ***Ring of Regeneration*** (*DMG 191*) is very rare (and requires attunement).  One effect of the ring, is that **you can regrow missing body parts after 1d6+1 days** if you have at least 1 hp for that whole time.  So dropping to 0 at all would reset the timer.

Comment: I don't have the stump. The berserker swallowed it. i could go back to the dungeon but if his stomach acid has burnt it up and its only like a little lump of meat will the spell still work?

Comment: @BrotherBrick the spell will also restore lost parts after... um... 2 minutes?

Comment: @BrotherBrick yeah, you don't need the part. The nose will grow back after two minutes. It's just that if you do happen to still have the part, and you put in place, it'll reattach instantly. (The distinction is important because in a fight, for instance, it could be the difference between spending 20 rounds waiting for your sword arm to grow back or being instantly ready.)

Comment: @NickBrown, why does evil genie not aplly on spells below 8th level?

Comment: @PeregrineLennert In 5e, 'Cast a spell of 8th Level or below' is one of the effects explicitly enumerated as within the scope of a wish spell, and thus isn't subject to the 'outside scope' DM call. It's actually the only completely painless one, since it's also explicitly excluded from the normal stress consequences for the caster.

Answer (score 12):

## Pay a spellcaster for their services.

I can think of a few spells that would work, but some of it gets a bit weird. As far as I know, none of them require the missing body part.

- Clone - 8th level wizard spell. Requires you to die, though.
- Resurrection - 7th level bard/cleric spell. Also requires you to die.
- Regenerate - 7th level Bard/Cleric/Druid spell
- Reincarnate - 5th level Druid spell. Also requires you to die.

Then you just need to find a caster that will do it for you and raise money (heh).

While not "rules", these can be considered "guidelines" for purchasing spells.

- [Adventurers League Dungeon Master's Guide (v2.1 “SKT”)](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/AL_DMG_SKT.pdf)
- [Adventurers League Player's Guide (v1.0 “ToD”)](http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/ADVLeague_PlayerGuide_TODv1_print.pdf)

<sup>PS - this might not work and poses potentially the most risk. Flesh to Stone. 6th level wizard/warlock spell. Be turned to stone, then get a stonemason to "repair" your nose. Then get turned back into flesh with Greater Restoration, a 5th level cleric/druid spell.</sup>

Comment: Thanks i'll see if my tribe's druid will do it. I won't look like Voldemort anymore!

Comment: Note that reincarnation has the nasty side-effect of probably ***changing your race***!  Plus getting killed on purpose seems a bit extreme to me, but they are possibilities.

Comment: @NickBrown haha, yea. these are pretty extreme options, but they are technically options.

Comment: i think i'll go with the stone one from @goodguy5. i'll be a bit harder but probably worth it.

Comment: you're risking a lot on the skill of the mason, and may loose the new nose to frostbite if it doesn't come back with the right blood vessels etc.

Comment: @Jasen: Beyond that, the only way that Greater Restoration would give you back your nose is if they shaped your existing stone to make the new nose (warping your face to do it). If they use some other stone to add the nose back, it was never part of you, so Greater Restoration wouldn't turn it into a flesh and blood nose. This isn't a 2E-style Stone to Flesh spell that converts arbitrary stone to something fleshy; Greater Restoration just undoes magical problems, so unless the stone used for your new nose was made from Flesh to Stone transformed stone (nose transplants FTW?), it stays stone.

Comment: @goodguy5 It's a shame Revivify doesn't restore lost body parts.

Answer (score 4):

## Get a magical prosthetic.

*Eberron: Rising from the Last War* introduces the Prosthetic Limb and Arcane Propulsion Arm magic items, while the Dungeon Master’s Guide includes the artifacts known as the Hand and Eye of Vecna.

When attuned and attached to the relevant stump or cavity left be the lost body part, these items grant restored functionality thereby negate the penalties for missing the replaced body part.