# My character's hand was cut off and lost, how can I regrow a hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, injury, regeneration

So yesterday I was playing D&D with my group and my right hand was cut off. I really love my rogue character and I don't want him with one hand because of all the disadvantages. I thought that I could  tie my hand with my crossbow, then again it will be hard for so many things. My final thought is to find a Master Cleric and if he has resurrection or clone spell, if not then I say to leave my character live his life as an npc and stop the adventures once and for all (meaning to create a new character).

How can I regrow my hand hand?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. First of all, what RPG and edition are you asking about? There are thousands of RPGs out there. You can indicate this by editing the appropriate tag (e.g. [dnd-5e]) into your post. In addition, what exactly is your question? If you're asking what spells there are to regenerate missing body parts, that is answerable (and may already have been answered). However, it's currently quite open-ended in asking for "thoughts", which is a bit too broad/vague to be answerable.

Comment: There are also some things that would be helpful to know: Does the party still have access to the hand that was lost? How much time has passed since you lost the hand? Also, are there any spellcasters in the party and what level is the party?

Comment: No we lost the hand..When the hand was cutted i fell unconscious and i woke up 5 hours later...I am level 7 we have a wizard level 7 and a druid level 7

Comment: @John Would it be accurate to say your question is "My character's hand was cut off and lost, how can I regrow a hand?" I think we can answer that question!

Comment: @jgn youre right im sorry but im a new here :(

Comment: @John Does [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116098/45757) answer your question ?

Comment: Or [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150521/how-to-get-a-characters-limb-regrown-at-3rd-level?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: @PierreCathé The second one helped a lot! Thank you