# How can I replace a lost Horn?

Tags: dnd-5e, tiefling, injury

So I play a tiefling phoenix sorcerer (lvl 9) and we had an encounter with two half-dragons in a forest. At first there was only one and me being a sorcerer I stayed back and used ranged attacks but the other one sneaked up on me and because of his action surge he absolutely massacred me. I was on deathsaves and he finished me with his lightning breath-weapon while trying to hit my mates too. They finished him and took my body to the big city to see a high level cleric.

At the end I was revived, but now I'm missing one horn, my face is deformed and I have a huge scar on my torso. I'm working on a mask design and I'm always clothed so that's not a problem, but my character is very fond of his horns and now he's very depressed about it (he's depressed because he died but the horn thing makes it worse).

So then my question is: is there a way get my horn back, if not, any ideas on how to make a fake one (what material and how to wear/attach it)?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related, possible dupes: [How can I recover a missing body part without using wish?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116098/52137), and [How to get a character's limb regrown at 3rd level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150521/52137)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. The end of your question adds: "if not, any ideas on how to make a fake one (what material and how to wear/attach it)?" Idea-generation questions are a poor fit for the Stack Exchange format; there's no way to choose a single "best" answers, as all answers are equally valid. As such, I would recommend editing this portion out of your question.

Answer (score 30):

## The *regenerate* spell

The most straightforward RAW way of getting missing bodyparts back is to have somebody cast [*regenerate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/regenerate) on you.

> The target’s severed body members (fingers, legs, tails, and so on), if any, are restored after 2 minutes. If you have the severed part and hold it to the stump, the spell instantaneously causes the limb to knit to the stump.

This should regrow your horn after 2 minutes.

Comment: Backing that up, the DMG's optional [lingering injury](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Injuries) rules have examples for horrible scarring and lost appendages that specify that they can be fully healed by [Regenerate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/regenerate).

Comment: In a similar vein, a Ring of Regeneration should also work, although it will take a bit longer.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson I've already asked about the ring of regeneration and we came to the conclusion that I had to be already attuned before dying.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll ask my DM about it. We have a cleric so maybe I'll wait 4lvls and have him use it on me then. For now I'll probably get a prosthetic one because It will probably be expensive to find someone to cast it on me now, we just spent a lot of money buying magic items, and it would ruin the whole mask thing so yeah.

Comment: Any insight about regeneration and scars? This is a good answer as it is, but if you do have such insight it would make a good addition.

Answer (score 10):

### A simple wooden/steel replacement would work out.

[As @Theik already mentioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162848/how-can-i-replace-a-lost-horn/162849#162849), *Regenerate* would grow it back entirely.

However, depending on how much money the character has, and whether they think having a fancy replacement horn would be acceptable (imagine if he could get one made out of mithral or adamantine), I could see it being a good roleplaying opportunity for the character swapping stories in a tavern with the locals for potential respect. "Oh, you mean *this* horn? Well have you ever seen a half-dragon? No? Well, this one time, my crew and I were scouting out this forest..."

Answer (score 3):

That depends. Regenerate is very much a possibility.

But some animal horns do grow back if lost, so perhaps your tieflings does too, I'd sort that out with the DM before going to any extremes.

Comment: This is definitely worth a note, the horn will regrow after some time. Depending on the size of the horns this may take months or years.

Answer (score 1):

### A Prosthetic Limb

The [*prosthetic limb*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/prosthetic-limb) is a magic item from *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* (p. 278):

> This artificial limb replaces a hand, arm, foot, leg, or similar appendage that was lost or removed.

While it is usually found or crafted in the world of Eberron, you can ask your DM if his setting reached a similar technological level.

Comment: A horn is different from a limb in far more ways than it is similar.

Comment: @T.J.L. I say it would not be possible if it were antlers, but these are horns.

Comment: Limbs are used for locomotion or manipulation, horns are not limbs.

Comment: @T.J.L. It has similarities with them, that would be enough for me: it doesn't violently contradict RAW, it is cool and doesn't break anything.

Comment: A horn is not similar to a limb in almost any way except that it's attached to the body. It's like a claw/talon or teeth. It is generally used for offense, has no moving parts, and is hard and sturdy. A simple piece of metal or some painted wood would suffice to replace it. A prosthetic limb is simply overkill on what would be required to replace it.

Comment: @RevenantBacon can we agree prosthetic horn should be possible in a world where prosthetic arms are a thing? And that it probably should be cheaper, especially if it is only decorative? And that prosthetic limb rules are good starting point to make a prosthetic horn rulings?

Comment: @Mołot I've already made an answer suggesting a fake horn. It could certainly be cheaper, if it was made of some ordinary wood and paint with little detail, or incredibly expensive if it were made of gold and adamantine, and a very intricate amount of detail. No, the prosthetic limb rules are not an especially good place to start, because the horn is essentially an art object or possibly a weapon (if it were on a creature that could attack with its horns), not a magically enchanted useable limb. It's more comparable to a piercing or a sword than an arm or leg.

Answer (score 1):

## The *Mending* cantrip.

IF you still happen to have your old horn, or are able to get it, the [*Mending*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mending) cantrip description says it:

> repairs a single break or tear in an object you touch, such as a
> broken chain link, two halves of a broken key, a torn cloak, or a
> leaking wineskin. As long as the break or tear is no larger than 1
> foot in any dimension, you mend it, leaving no trace of the former
> damage.

Even if there are several breaks/tears in your old horn, *Mending* is only a cantrip and can be cast practically all day for free.

Comment: Seeing as the mending cantrip is for repairing object damage, I personally wouldn't let it be used in this manner if I was the DM. Neither would I let it reattach a severed finger or a toe

Comment: @rasmus91 I'd completely agree on the finger/toe. However, that degree of attachment is FAR more complex than a horn! Horn's aren't quiiiiiiite like the tips of your fingernails, but they're really close.

Comment: Which I still would not let mending fix. Say the cut piece of horn was sliced in two pieces: mending would definitely fix that. Buy I wouldn't let it reattach it. Just as I wouldn't let it reattach hair. But I suppose that's a matter of interpretation. In my view, mending can't be used to reattach things to a living creature.

Comment: Mending is not able to affect body parts, regardless of what type of body part the spell is affecting. It can only target objects, so considering one half of the horn is still part of a creature and not an object, the spell cannot reattach it.